# TensorFlow Variable Names - Assignment Error in Save/Restore

Tags: tensorflow

I am saving and restoring a TensorFlow model using `tf.train.Saver` `save` and `restore`. In the restore process I am loading new input data. The `restore` method throws this error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Assign requires shapes
>   of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1334,3] rhs shape= [1246,3] 
>   [[Node: save/Assign_6 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_2"],
>   use_locking=true, validate_shape=true,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Variable_2, save/RestoreV2_6)]]

This seems to say that the problem is in `Variable_2` but how does one determine which variable in the code corresponds to `Variable_2`?

Answer (score 1):

- If you are restoring the model and doing a feed forward, then the model shape and model architecture should be the same when you saved it
- So the above error is saying when you are restoring your model, one of the tensors which was saved has shape [1246,3] but you are assigning it to a tensor whose shape is [1334,3]
- to explicitly know which variables are of which name you can assign unique names to the tensors, for example `a = tf.placeholder("float", [3, 3], name="tensor_a")`
- So now when you restore the model you know your model has a tensor in the graph with name="tensor_a" which is of shape 3x3
- Quick Tutorial in Code :

  ```
  # Create some variables.
  v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", shape=[3], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
  v2 = tf.get_variable("v2", shape=[5], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)

  inc_v1 = v1.assign(v1+1)
  dec_v2 = v2.assign(v2-1)

  # Add an op to initialize the variables.
  init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

  # Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
  saver = tf.train.Saver()

  # Later, launch the model, initialize the variables, do some work, and save the
  # variables to disk.
  with tf.Session() as sess:
      sess.run(init_op)
      # Do some work with the model.
      inc_v1.op.run()
      dec_v2.op.run()
      # Save the variables to disk.
      save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
      print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)

  tf.reset_default_graph()

  # Create some variables.
  d1 = tf.get_variable("v1", shape=[3])
  d2 = tf.get_variable("v2", shape=[5])

  # Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
  saver = tf.train.Saver()

  # Later, launch the model, use the saver to restore variables from disk, and
  # do some work with the model.
  with tf.Session() as sess:
      # Restore variables from disk.
      saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
      print("Model restored.")
      # Check the values of the variables
      print("v1 : %s" % d1.eval())
      print("v2 : %s" % d2.eval())
  ```
- If you noticed in above code d1 and v1 have the same shape now if you change shape of any ofthe variable it will throw you a error which is similar to the error what you are getting

Answer (score -1):

When you create a new Variable it get's a unique name. Saver.restore looks at same name in checkpoint. If you need to initialize some of your variables from a different checkpoint with a different name, please take a look `tf.contrib.framework.init_from_checkpoint`.

Comment: Thanks but I am not quite following. I am using the same code that saved the checkpoint to load the checkpoint; no new variables were created between the save and restore.